# Validar que variable no es vacía y no excede una longitud

Tags: php

Desde un formulario envío un campo **valor**, y quiero procesar dicho campo siempre y cuando no sea vacío y no exceda la longitud de 15 caracteres.
Hice esto, pero igual muestra ***PROCESAR***.

```
if (strlen(!empty($_POST['valor'])) <= 15) {
    echo "PROCESAR";
}
```

Comment: a ver tienes un problema de logica `!empty($_POST['valor'])` devolvera true y luego haces `strlen(true')` obviamente siempre  va a ser < 15

Comment: ¿Qué valores puede tener la variable `$_POST['valor']`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Necesitas dos condiciones separadas.  No lo puedes hacer todo junto como lo tienes.  Como te explicaron en un comentario. La condcion `!empty($_POST['valor'])` va a evaluar siempre a `true` o `false`.  Cuando evalueas la segunda condicion, siempre va a ser `strlen(true)` o `strlen(false)`, y esos dos valores van a evaluar verdadero porque los dos son menores que 15. La forma correcta seria asi:

```
if (!empty($_POST['valor']) && strlen($_POST['valor']) <= 15) {
    echo "PROCESAR";
}
```

Comment: Podes explicar un poco mejor porque?

Answer (score 5):

### Tu problema

Primero y antes de saltar a dar una respuesta voy a explicar porque no funciona tu código.

De acuerdo a la documentación [`empty()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) nos regresará un booleano y [`strlen()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) nos regresará un entero, esto quiere decir que si hacemos

```
strlen(true)
```

o

```
strlen(false)
```

Nos regresará 0 y 1 respectivamente, como sabemos 1 y 0 son menores o iguales a 15 por lo que tu condición pase lo que pase siempre será verdadera.

---

### Respuesta

Por otro lado lo que no toman en cuenta ninguna de las respuestas es que si `$_POST['valor']` es `'0'`, la validación `!empty($_POST['valor'])` nos dará como resultado *false* por lo que no entrará en la condición.

Si necesitamos que el valor no esté vacío podemos hacerlo con el comparador `!==` de esta forma

```
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
if ($valor !== '' && strlen($valor) <= 15) {
    echo "PROCESAR";
}
```

Lo que nos dará paso a otro problema, ¿qué pasa si la variable no existe o es null?

Yo sugiero que para no tener falsos negativos revisemos que la variable exista y luego revisamos que no sea `''`, de esta forma:

```
$valor = $_POST['valor'];
if (isset($valor) && $valor !== '' && strlen($valor) <= 15) {
    echo "PROCESAR";
}
```

Comment: Con el ternario funciona tanto si `$valor` es igual a: `0, '0', NULL, FALSE, ''`... funciona en todos los casos.

Comment: @A.Cedano no, http://rextester.com/BTJQC84092. A menos que yo no esté entendiendo el problema :)

Answer (score 4):

Otra posibilidad sería usar un operador ternario, del siguiente modo:

```
$status=(!empty($_POST['valor'])) && (strlen($_POST['valor']) <= 15) ? "PROCESAR" : "NO PROCESAR";
```

#### Ejemplos:

En los ejemplos que siguen, la variable `$status` adquiere un valor u otro según el caso:

```
$valor=NULL; //$_POST['valor']

$status=(!empty($valor)) && (strlen($valor) <= 15) ? "PROCESAR" : "NO PROCESAR";
echo $status;
echo PHP_EOL;
```

***Salida:***

```
NO PROCESAR
```

---

```
$valor="PALABRADEMASDEQUINCE";
$status=(!empty($valor)) && (strlen($valor) <= 15) ? "PROCESAR" : "NO PROCESAR";
echo $status;    
echo PHP_EOL;
```

***Salida:***

```
NO PROCESAR
```

---

```
$valor="PALABRADEQUINCE";
$status=(!empty($valor)) && (strlen($valor) <= 15) ? "PROCESAR" : "NO PROCESAR";
echo $status;
```

***Salida:***

```
PROCESAR
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Saludos debería ser de este modo

```
$var = 'foos';

if(!empty($var) && strlen($var) >3){
  echo "exito";
}else{
  echo "fallo";
}
```

> Con !empty indicas que mientras la variable no este vacía  con el
>
> operador && siginifica AND es un operador lógico; se esta usando para indicar que para que la instrucción se ejecute necesita que ambas comparaciones ocurran

```
if ((!empty($_POST['valor']) && strlen($_POST['valor']) <= 15) {
    echo "PROCESAR";
}
```

> Como tu enunciado dicta que para que la variable sea válida no debe
>   estar vacia y no debe ser mayor a 15 entonces primero lo comprobamos
>   con la función empty pero negandola ya que el resultado que te
>   devuelve es booleano, true o false, posterior al hacer esa revisión
>   ahora procedemos con la longitud y si ambas condiciones se cumplen
>   entonces accedemos al valor del if en caso contrario con alguna de las
>   condiciones que no se cumpla te mandrá al return que pongas en el
>   false

Comment: el operador && no indica que despues sigue otra instruccion.. significa AND y es un operador logico.

Comment: cierto @gbianchi lo agregaré pues no me supe explicar